# C++ Regex to match words without punctuation

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

I searched, couldn't find anything. In the interest of not wasting any more of my time on the chance that the answer is obvious to someone else, I'm asking here. Only site that has been useful so far is this one: http://softwareramblings.com/2008/07/regular-expressions-in-c.html but the samples are far too simplistic. I'm using Visual studio 2010.

```
#include <regex>

[...]

string seq = "Some words. And... some punctuation.";
regex rgx("\w");

smatch result;
regex_search(seq, result, rgx);

for(size_t i=0; i<result.size(); ++i){
    cout << result[i] << endl;
}
```

Expected output would be:

Some
 words
 And
 some
 punctuation

Thanks.

Comment: I don't blame you for not getting this right.  The documentation I've seen on this blows hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things here.

First, your regex string needs to have the `\` escaped.  Its still a C++ string, after all.

```
regex rgx("\\w");
```

Also, the regex `\w`matches just one "word character".  If you want to match an entire word, you need to use:

```
regex rgx("\\w+");
```

Finally, in order to iterate through all possible matches, then you need to use an iterator.  Here's a complete working example:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string seq = "Some words. And... some punctuation.";
    regex rgx("\\w+");

    for( sregex_iterator it(seq.begin(), seq.end(), rgx), it_end; it != it_end; ++it )
        cout << (*it)[0] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot about needing to still escape the string. The other answer posted worked, the only addition I need is for it to ignore any words with only numbers.

Comment: @Chris:  @Eugene beat me to it, because I took the extra time to explain more things & give you a complete working example :)

Comment: @Chris:  More tricky.  You'll need to use some form of lookahead, methinks.  Take a look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Comment: It's probably easier to discard "digit-only" results in a second stage. It's of course trivial with a regex, but there are plenty of other ways (eg. `find_first_not_of`)

Comment: @MSalters:  Yeah, I'd probably do that too.

Comment: I got mad why my string was not being matched until I found that I needed to escape '\'. Thanks for helping me keep my sanity one more day.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string seq = "Some words. And... some punctuation.";
regex rgx("(\\w+)");

regex_iterator<string::iterator> it(seq.begin(), seq.end(), rgx);
regex_iterator<string::iterator> end;

for (; it != end; ++it)
{
    cout << it->str() << endl;
}
```